# Is the equation of the derivative of a loss function relative to the input to the Sigmoid (z) the same whether computed backward or forward?

Tags: logistic, loss-functions, derivative

I am referring to the derivative of the binary cross-entropy loss function for logistic regression. Using back-propagation, the derivative of the loss function `L` with respect to `z` is `a - y`, where a is the output of the sigmoid function given `z`. Here, `z` is the polynomial that takes the parameters `w`, data values `x`, and bias value `b`.

[image: Derivative of loss function L relative to polynomial input (z) to sigmoid function.]

Assume I tried to find an equation for the derivative of the loss function from left to right. I think I would still get `dL/dz` = `a - y` as if I used back-propagation. Is that correct? As a side note, how would you calculate the derivative from left to right? Is it practical or useful in some situations?

---

This StackExchange question gives more details about how this derivative equation is made:
[Derivative of the loss function w.r.t to X for the backpropagation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387618/derivative-of-the-loss-function-w-r-t-to-x-for-the-backpropagation)

I also used this article as reference:

[Derivation of DL/dz](https://community.deeplearning.ai/t/derivation-of-dl-dz/165)